# Matched substrings from a List of strings

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List` of Strings like this

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Birth City", "City of Birth", "Location", "Geo Address", "Last Known Address");
```

I want to extract a `List` of Strings that are similar (by similar I mean any substrings matching).

I want `Birth City, City of Birth, Geo address, Last known address` as the first two has birth as a match and the next two has Address as a match.

I'm trying with this, but I know I'm missing something here

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("Birth City", "City of Birth", "Location", "Geo Address", "Last Known Address");

           myList.stream().forEach(line -> {
               System.out.println(getMatchingSubstring(line,myList));
           });

 private static String getMatchingSubstring(String str, List<String> substrings) {
        for (String substring : substrings) {
            if (str.contains(substring)) {
                return substring;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your request seems ambiguous, are your strings to search birth and address, and what is your expected result? Maybe would be better to use regular expressions.

Comment: Your code makes no sense.  You are simply matching keywords in the list to the same list of keywords.  You need to better explain your ultimate goal.   And be careful when you use the term substring as `it` is a substring of `city` which would match any phrase that contained the word `city`, among other words too.

Answer (score 2):

Your method `getMatchingSubstring` gets each element of `myList`, and `myList` itself, then checks for each string in the list - whether it contains the provided string. And since the provided string is always one of the list elements - it will be printed once.

Some suggestions:

1. First thing I'd do is to pass the list without the current element (`line`) to avoid comparison with the same string.
2. Instead of comparing strings - I'd split the string by the space character and compare to tokens to find intersection between strings. This is the similarity you're talking about.
3. Print only the lines that didn't return as null from `getMatchingSubstring`.

It will look something like that:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("Birth City", "City of Birth", "Location", "Geo Address", "Last Known Address");

    myList.stream().forEach(line -> {
      String result = getMatchingSubstring(line,
          myList.stream().filter(element -> !element.equals(line)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
      if (result != null){
        System.out.println(result);
      }
    });
  }

  private static String getMatchingSubstring(String str, List<String> otherStrings) {
    String[] strTokens = str.split(" ");
    for (String substring : otherStrings) {
      String[] subStringTokens = substring.split(" ");
      if (intersection(strTokens, subStringTokens)) {
        return substring;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  private static boolean intersection(String[] a, String[] b) {
    List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList(a);
    List<String> l2 = Arrays.asList(b);
    Set<String> result = l1.stream().distinct().filter(l2::contains).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    return result.size() > 0;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
City of Birth
Birth City
Last Known Address
Geo Address
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal, you could first break down each `String` of your main `List` with a regex which splits by white spaces. Then, you could traverse your main `List` by index with an `IntStream` and for each broken down array corresponding to the i-th `String` verify if any of its words appear in other strings with a nested stream. If they do, then they pass the `filter` aggregate operation and then they're collected; otherwise they're discarded.

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Birth City", "City of Birth", "Location", "Geo Address", "Last Known Address");

//Breaking down each String by white spaces
List<String[]> listSplitStr = list.stream()
        .map(str -> str.split("\\s+"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<String> listRes = IntStream.range(0, list.size())  //Traversing the list of broken down strings by index
        .filter(i -> Arrays.stream(listSplitStr.get(i)).anyMatch(word -> //for each array of the broken down list we check if any of its words appear in the main list
                IntStream.range(0, list.size()).anyMatch(j -> !list.get(i).equals(list.get(j)) && list.get(j).contains(word))))  //Traversing the main list again and making sure that the string we're iterating does not correspond to the current array and that the array's word is contained within the string
        .mapToObj(i -> list.get(i)) //Retrieving the i-th string from the main list
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(listRes);
```

This is the output as the one you expected:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> if (str.contains(substring)) {

You are essentially comparing whole string against the list of input.
Hence, returns true for all

As a naive approach, you might need to split the string based on white space and check

```
private static List<String> getMatchingSubstring(List<String> substrings) {
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < substrings.size(); i++) {
            if (!result.contains(substrings.get(i))) {
                String[] tokens = substrings.get(i).split("\\u0020");
                for (String token : tokens) {
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < substrings.size(); j++) {
                        if (!result.contains(substrings.get(j)) && substrings.get(j).contains(token)) {
                            result.add(substrings.get(i));
                            result.add(substrings.get(j));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

[image]

Further, you can check for string Fuzzy matching algorithms [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching) in case of complex matching scenario.